# What do you think is wrong with following reasoning of 'students'?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

> Albert announces to his class that he plans to surprise them with a
>   quiz sometime next week.
>
> His students first wonder if the quiz could be on Friday of next next.
>   They reason that it can’t: if Albert didn’t give the quiz before
>   Friday, then by midnight Thursday, they would know the quiz had to be
>   on Friday, and so the quiz wouldn’t be a surprise any more.
>
> Next the students wonder whether Albert could give the surprise quiz
>   Thursday. They observe that if the quiz wasn’t given before Thursday,
>   it would have to be given on the Thursday, since they already know it
>   can’t be given on Friday. But having figured that out, it wouldn’t be
>   a surprise if the quiz was on Thursday either. Similarly, the students
>   reason that the quiz can’t be on Wednesday, Tuesday, or Monday.
>   Namely, it’s impossible for Albert to give a surprise quiz next week.
>   All the students now relax, having concluded that Albert must have
>   been bluffing.
>
> And since no one expects the quiz, that’s why, when Albert gives it on
>   Tuesday next week, it really is a surprise!

Comment: This is a variant of [Unexpected hanging paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not if a quiz is a surprise, but when a quiz is a surprise. The students’ argument only demonstrates that one will always have foreknowledge of the quiz as *some point* beforehand, but up until the day before you don’t know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a large literature on this sort of puzzle. [For a helpful introduction, start here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-paradoxes/).